# What does Travis Bickle mean when he says 'I need to get organizized' In Taxi Driver

Tags: plot-explanation, taxi-driver

In the movie [***Taxi Driver***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075314/) there is this scene where Travis Buckle invites Betsy into a coffee shop and they start talking.

What does he really mean by "organizized, Its a joke" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Travis-Bickle-mean-when-he-says-I-need-to-get-organizized)

> It refers to a novelty poster that was popular in the late 1970s at the time the film was made.  It's the kind of gag gift that a white-collar worker might hang in his or her cubicle.  When he mentions the phrase on his date with Betsy, it suggests that the working-class Travis Bickle has white-collar aspirations, but he doesn't have the intellectual or economic wherewithal to carry them out.  You can see the poster in a still from the film below.

[image]

[You can buy them online](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0187Q5W4M)

[image]